# Rjust method alignment

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, text-align

Here is the simple code:

```
OS.write(ip+re.search(version,data).group(0).rjust(25)+'\n')
```

All I want is to have the output like this:

```
10.102.19.1           version=6.40.7
10.102.41.1           version=6.40.7
10.102.3.1            version=6.40.8
```

But have the right string absolutely doesnt want to be aligned and I always get this:

```
10.102.19.1           version=6.40.7
10.102.41.1           version=6.40.7
10.102.3.1           version=6.40.8
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial solution might be,

```
OS.write(ip + re.search(version, data).group(0).rjust(30 - len(ip)) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. Could you explain me why simple rjust() method didnt work in my case?

Comment: Apparently, your `ip` is not constant length, I have made your code just a little more dynamic. @Dover